# bash why no match with number on regexp

Tags: bash

I'm curious why this code does not match -- take the "then" branch.  It echos "no match"  Can you please advise?

```
 #!/bin/bash

 suffix="2"

 if [[ $suffix =~ "^[0-9]+$" ]]
 then
    echo "match"
 else
    echo "no match"
 fi
```

Comment: Too many quotes! (Not often you get told *that* about bash, eh?)

Comment: Dog gone it, I just realized that from before.

Comment: It will sink in eventually. I could have sworn it worked before with a pre-4.0 BASH version

Comment: Ahh, try 3.1.17, it works (matches)! -- with the quotes.  That's what I was running before.

Comment: Heh -- rather a surprise, there. I'll need to go review the changelog...

Comment: ...btw, the common wisdom is to put your regex in a variable and use that variable unquoted on the right-hand side of `=~` to have consistent behavior across all releases supporting the operator. I don't personally follow that much myself (because who has pre-3.2 releases anymore?), but... well, that question seem to have an answer. :)

Comment: Too funny, the company I work at gave me a pre 3.2 install a month ago (in the cygwin release they keep).   I'm not allowed to download my own software, generally speaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the right-hand side of an `=` or `=~` operation within `[[ ]]` in modern (3.2+) releases of bash makes the string literal -- ie. no longer a regex or pattern.

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string.

---

For consistent behavior across releases supporting `=~` (if one needs to support versions prior to 3.2), accepted best practice is to put your regex in a variable, and use that variable unquoted on the right-hand side of `=~`:

```
re='^[0-9]+$'
[[ $suffix =~ $re ]]
```

Comment: That makes sense for `=`, since it decides whether to do an exact or pattern match based on the syntax of the right-hand side. I wonder why `=~` works this way, since it's specifically defined to do a regexp match.

Comment: @Barmar, a few things. First, `=~` has use in that manner, to give you an unanchored match. Second, you can quote only *part of* the right-hand side of a `=~` expression to have some characters treated as literal and others as regex.

Comment: @Charles please see last comment under question (and run it if you can)

Comment: @Barmar, ...example: `[[ $foo =~ ^[0-9a-f]+-"$var" ]]`, to match an exact/literal string preceded only by hex digits and a dash.

Comment: That makes sense, since there's nothing like `preg_quote()` in bash.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Nice explanation. If the string you want to match is `"foo"` with quotes around them I presume standard escaping is all that is required?

Comment: `[[ $var =~ '"foo"' ]]` would do the right thing in that case, if that's what you mean (and if the "right thing" you're referring to is unanchored).